# Accessing rowObejct inside custom_element

Tags: jqgrid

According to the documentation it's possible to write own function for creating custom input element for cell:

```
<script>
function myelem (value, options) {
  var el = document.createElement("input");
  el.type="text";
  el.value = value;
  return el;
}

function myvalue(elem, operation, value) {
    if(operation === 'get') {
       return $(elem).find("input").val();
    } else if(operation === 'set') {
       $('input',elem).val(value);
    }
}
jQuery("#grid_id").jqGrid({
...
   colModel: [ 
      ... 
      {name:'price', ..., editable:true, edittype:'custom', editoptions:    {custom_element: myelem, custom_value:myvalue} },
      ...
   ]
...
});
</script>
```

Is it possible to access rowObject from custom_element (myelem) function, because I have to create different controls (input, select) depending on rowObject data (e.g rowObject.type)?

Answer (score 2):

You are right, it could be practical to have `rowObject` parameter which not exist. As a workaround I could suggest to use `options` parameter of the [custom_element](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acommon_rules#custom) (in your example `myelem`) function.

If custom control for editing will be created the object having `id` and `name` properties will be used as the `options` parameter. The `id` will be id of the new created elements and the name is the value from the `name` property of `colModel` of the corresponding column. You can use the fact that the `id` value will be constructed from the rowid and it will be appended by underscore and the column name (the `name` property). So the `options.id` is rowid + '_' + `options.name` and you can easy get the value of current `rowid`. Then using [getRowData](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3amethods) you can get `rowObject`, which you need. Instead of [getRowData](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3amethods) you can use [getCell](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3amethods) of cause.